# when is mapDispatchToProps function used

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have come across this piece of code while learning react-redux

```
export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, getState) => {
    return ActionCreators({completeDriver}, dispatch, getState); 
};
```

I want to know when to use this function.

Answer (score 0):

as per redux actions are dispatched like `dispatch(actionCreator())`
for doing so inside an react component you need the reference of dispatch which need to be passed as prop to your component.

so if you use [connect()](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) you can reduce this passing of dispatch as prop by yourself this thing will be handed via connect [HOC(Higher Order Component)](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.4m4r0t82l).

for larger scale application using mapDispatchToProps of connect would saves lot of dev time of wiring things.